# ListView does not re-render changed rows

Tags: listview, react-native

I have a small collection of simple objects, which contains following keys: position (left/right), last. The `last` property determines whether the object is last element in specific position.

For example, collection can looks as follow:

```
[{position: 'left', last: false},
{position: 'left', last: false},
{position: 'left', last: true},
{position: 'right', last: false},
{position: 'right', last: true}]
```

When adding new object to collection, I change previous object if required.

Now I can go to my question, why changed rows are not re-rendered?
Here is my ListView configuration:

```
dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
    rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 != r2
})
```

Method updating the list

```
_updateList(messages) {
    messages = messages.map((row, index) => {
        let last = false;
        let next = messages[index+1];
        if((next != undefined && next.position != row.position) || next == undefined)
            last = true;

        row.last = last;
        return row;
    });

    var rowIds = messages.map((row, index) => index).reverse();

    this.setState({
        messages: messages,
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(messages, rowIds)
    }, () => {
        console.log(this.state.dataSource);
    });
}
```

Render component

```
<ListView
    renderScrollComponent={props => <InvertibleScrollView {...props} inverted />}
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    style={{flex: 1, padding: 4*vw}}
    renderRow={(data) => <Message {...data}/>}
/>
```

Comment: My question concerns react-native

Comment: Sorry, I had this post shown in the **android** question list... :O

Comment: Can you show us how you render your list ?

Comment: There may be an error here: `var rowIds = messages.map((row, index) => index).reverse();`

Comment: Nope, it's not the reason.

Comment: Just realized you are populating the ListVie dataSource with multiple arguments, it says on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html that you can only populate the dataSource with an array.

Comment: You are wrong, cloneWithRows has multiple arguments.